# Kotlin/Java - Default Fraction Digits of the Currency Class

Tags: java, kotlin, currency

Consider the following Kotlin code sample:

```
import java.util.*

fun main(vararg args: String) {
    Currency
        .getAvailableCurrencies()
        .sortedBy { it.currencyCode }
        .forEach {
            val cc = it.currencyCode
            val fd = it.defaultFractionDigits
            println("$cc = $fd")
        }
}
```

Example output:

> ADP = 0
>
> AED = 2
>
> AFA = 2
>
> ...
>
> XAG = -1

What I want to know specifically relating to *currencies* such as XAG (Troy Ounce of Silver), what is meant by having a -1 (negative 1) fractional digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the case of pseudo-currencies, such as IMF Special Drawing Rights,
>   -1 is returned.

So it just means that XAG isn't a real currency.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Currency#getDefaultFractionDigits()